# How to create a windows service with Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

How to create a windows service with Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2 using Mongrel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few years ago `mongrel_service` extension to Mongrel used to provide functionality to run a Rails application (using mongrel_service) as a service.

Due some changes in Rails 3 and the lack of continious development in Mongrel, there has been no update of mongrel internals to handle the newer version of Rails properly

Because of that, mongrel_service can't be used to run a Rails 3 application with Mongrel as a service.

However, as author of the original mongrel_service, I'm close to release an updated library that will be able to run a Rails, Thin or any time of Ruby application as Windows Service.

This requires a little bit more testing so is not ready for public. Announcement will be posted at [my blog](http://blog.mmediasys.com/) and also [RubyInstaller Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller)

ETA less than a week (after RailsConf completes)

Sorry for not been able to help you better than that.

Comment: Thank you Luis, I will wait this release very anxious.

Comment: Ted: work as jumped in my way, but the initial working version is here: https://github.com/luislavena/service_wrapper missing docs and binaries, will blog once I complete environment assignation to it.

Comment: I'm really keen to use service_wrapper but have been unable to figure out how to build/install it. I've asked a question about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630512/. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've answered my previous question about how to implement this at stackoverflow.com/questions/7630512