# run rails in background process -windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3.2, detach

I have created one desktop browser application on the rails installer on windows pc. Now I am trying to run `rails s -p3001 -e production -d`. It does not run on the pc.

How to detach the application server process on the windows pc?

Here is the error

```
=> Booting Thin
 > Rails 3.2.7 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
C:/ibt/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib
/active_support/core_ext/process/daemon.rb:3:in `fork': fork() function is unimp
lemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
    from C:/ibt/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
 ort-3.2.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/process/daemon.rb:3:in `daemon'
    from C:/ibt/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `daemonize_app'
    from C:/ibt/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
 /lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from C:/ibt/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from C:/ibt/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/ibt/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/ibt/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
     from script/rails:6:in `require'
     from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The option `-d` is for making the server run in the background; so you are doing it right. What (error) message do you get when you run the command?

Comment: Hi @PrakashMurthy  . I have just updated my question Please check the logs .. This is on windows pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question with reference of the link :: [run rails in background process -windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630512/how-do-i-install-this-service-wrapper-for-mongrel-rails-on-my-windows-server)

Thanks for the answers Murthy

Comment: I have created the service files adding exe file and conf file within the folder. Now my app is working on the automatic service.

Answer (score 1):

The error message makes it very clear: `fork() function is unimp
lemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)`.

The way rails server is daemonized is by calling the `fork system call` on the machine. Here is the relevant code from the rails repo: [`exit if fork`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/process/daemon.rb#L3)

It is failing on the windows pc because `Windows Operating System` doesn't implement a `fork` system call.

One option might be to install `Cygwin` on the windows pc as suggested in [this answer to What is the closest thing windows has to fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/985374/429758)

Comment: This is a good Answer But I wwas not able to create background process  on the windows .I have created service by it self on the windows. But thank you @Prakash