# Running webrick server in background for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, background, windows-7, webrick

I want to run Webrick server in background on Windows, tried following with no luck :

```
>rails s -d
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:283: warning: circular argument reference - now
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:327:in `daemon': daemon() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:327:in `daemonize_app'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630512/how-do-i-install-this-service-wrapper-for-mongrel-rails-on-my-windows-server

Comment: Thanks @AliMasudianPour.. I will check that & get back..

Comment: @AliMasudianPour Its working for me,could you please add it as an answer, so I wcan assign bounty to your answer.

Comment: @Shruti I added the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution from [Ali MasudianPour and brad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9321474/5157221):

Download `service_wrapper-0.1.0-win32.zip` from https://github.com/luislavena/service_wrapper/downloads and extract `service_wrapper.exe` from `bin/`. I extracted it to `C:\service_wrapper`.

Next set up a configuration file. I used the hello example and modified it for my app then placed it in the `C:\service_wrapper` directory.

```
; Service section, it will be the only section read by service_wrapper
[service]

; Provide full path to executable to avoid issues when executable path was not
; added to system PATH.
executable = C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe

; Provide there the arguments you will pass to executable from the command line
arguments = C:\railsapp\script\rails s -e production

; Which directory will be used when invoking executable.
; Provide a full path to the directory (not to a file)
directory = C:\railsapp

; Optionally specify a logfile where both STDOUT and STDERR of executable will
; be redirected.
; Please note that full path is also required.
logfile = C:\railsapp\log\service_wrapper.log
```

Now just create the service with

```
sc create railsapp binPath= "C:\service_wrapper\service_wrapper.exe C:\service_wrapper\service_wrapper.conf" start= auto
```

(watch for the spaces after `binPath=` and `start=`. It won't work without them)

Then start it with

```
net start railsapp
```

And you're home and hosed!